# Issue with HTML5 video working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, jsfiddle

I'm trying to get this video player to work in IE. I've tried using the video.js but it failed to work on anything (even following the instructions didn't do the trick).

Here's the link to a jsFiddle example:

1 - [Working example in FF, Chrome, Opera, and Safari](http://jsfiddle.net/nickhiebert/H9yt9/)

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div role="videos">
            <video controls preload width="478" height="266" poster="images/ipad-poster.jpg" id="videoPlayer">
            <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="videos/video1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="videos/video1.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </div><!-- end videos -->               
</section>
```

CSS:

```
div[role="videos"] {
    background: url('images/ipad_smaller.png') no-repeat;
    width: 788px;
    height: 573px;
    margin: 195px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[role="videos"] video {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 140px 0 0 10px;
}
```

2 - [video.js attempt, doesn't work in any browser](http://jsfiddle.net/nickhiebert/ZT7DU/)

HTML:

```
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
<script>videojs.options.flash.swf = "videos/video1.swf"</script>
<div role="videos">
    <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="478" height="266"  data-setup="{"controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto"}">
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
        <source src="videos/video1.webm" type='video/webm' />
        <source src="videos/video1.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    </video>
```

Just hoping for some more direction, if I'm close or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow was to anal about posting links, so I posted them like that. I don't have time for bad protocols on this website.

Comment: you can`t post links with spaces in there...